# Error decrypting using AES GCM in Python; AttributeError: 'Cipher' object has no attribute 'decrypt'

Tags: python, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I am sending some information to a https server and receving a response. To increase the privary, I want to use some kind of encryption.

I am sending json data and I am encrypting the data as following

I am using Python3.6

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.hkdf import HKDF
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, hmac
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
 
salt = os.urandom(16)
 
password = b'password'
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
length=32,
salt=salt,
iterations=10000
)
key = kdf.derive(password)

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.GCM(salt), backend=default_backend())
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

data = {'xxxx': xxxx, 'xxxx': xxxx}

encrypted_data = encryptor.update(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')) + encryptor.finalize()
tag = encryptor.tag
```

Now, I am trying to decrypt the data as following

```
encrypted_data_b64 = request['encrypted_data']
tag_b64 = request['tag']
salt_b64 = request['salt']

encrypted_data = base64.b64decode(encrypted_data_b64)
tag = base64.b64decode(tag_b64)
salt = base64.b64decode(salt_b64)

password = b'password'
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
length=32,
salt=salt,
iterations=10000
)
key = kdf.derive(password)

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.GCM(salt), backend=default_backend())
decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data, tag)
```

getting error :

> AttributeError: 'Cipher' object has no attribute 'decrypt'

Also, tried

```
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
decrypted_data = decryptor.update(encrypted_data) + decryptor.finalize()
```

Gettting error:

> ```
> "Authentication tag must be provided when decrypting." ValueError: Authentication tag must be provided when decrypting.
> ```

So, I tried

> decrypted_data = decryptor.update(encrypted_data) +
> decryptor.finalize(tag) TypeError: finalize() takes 1 positional
> argument but 2 were given

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: `modes.GCM(salt)` is supposed to be `modes.GCM(nonce, tag)` on decrypt and `modes.GCM(nonce)` on encrypt. The rest of the issues can be resolved by looking at the [example in the documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes.GCM). You can use the salt as the nonce if you want though the nonce should ideally be just 12 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. The mistake was that in the decrypt side the cipher needs to be created with `modes.GCM(salt, tag)` rather than just `modes.GCM(salt)` - as you mentioned.